# Abort the checkout from order guide based on the requestor background check(if not completed) in ServiceNow

Tags: javascript, servicenow, aws-service-catalog

I am having a requirement related to order guide.
When the user is selected in 'Requested for' and the workstation is selected, it should check the ID and BG check if completed or not (marked true on User table form). If false, it should show a display msg in Red 'User BG check is not completed'.

It should display the same msg on the next two items in order guide and should not allow to checkout.

This requirement is related to ServiceNow. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a reference qualifier on the requested for field to not allow selection of invalid users in the first place?

Comment: Hey Nick, they don't want this. They just want a display msg so that other users should know what to do.